# How to transfer Woocommerce product-reviews from one product to another

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, review

I have a problem that when I go to Edit on a Woocommerce product, it does not load the most recent product data. This means that I have to re-enter all the product data after each change, because otherwise, it would be back to what it was a few months ago.

This problem only occurs with one specific product and I have found that if I copy everything from that product to a newly created product, the error no longer occurs. Therefore, this solution seems to make more sense to me than looking for the actual cause of the error.

The only problem now is that the original product has already collected many reviews and I don't want to lose them.

As far as I understand correctly, reviews are saved as comments in Wordpress/Woocommerce. So I tried the following for the transfer:

```sql
UPDATE gowp_comments
SET comment_post_ID = [new_product_id]
WHERE comment_post_ID = [old_product_id] AND comment_type = 'review';
```

While it changes all IDs correctly, when I test the new product with "$product->get_average_rating()" I get 0. I also noted that the product itself had the property "comment_count" (which I found a bit odd since it seems redundant to me). But changing this as well made no difference.

Did I miss something? I'm trying to figure out, why woocommerce isn't handling these transfered reviews correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *gowp_comments* table and the *comment_count* property aren't the only two things you need to change.

WooCommerce also stores reviewCount, the count of each possible rating and the review-average separately in the table *gowp_postmeta*

If you just created a new product you need to update the properties *_wc_average_rating* and *_wc_review_count* accordingly.

You also need to create a new postmeta-entry with key name *_wc_rating_count* which is an array storing how often each rating was given. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `gowp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES (NULL, '1234', '_wc_rating_count', 'a:2:{i:5;i:22;i:4;i:33;i:1;i:23}');
```